# how to default sort wpf listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I implemented sorting on my listview following [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745786.aspx). How do I get my list to default sort when the window is opened? I tried:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SortCustomerList("CustomerName", ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        }
```

...but I'm getting "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"...with an inner exception of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

[EDIT] I moved the call to sort to the loaded event as suggested, but I still get the exception? Here's what the sort method and loaded event looks like:

```
private void SortCustomerList(string sortBy, ListSortDirection direction)
{
   ICollectionView dataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(customersListView.ItemsSource);

   dataView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
   SortDescription sd = new SortDescription(sortBy, direction);
   dataView.SortDescriptions.Add(sd);
   dataView.Refresh();
}

private void mainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   SortCustomerList("CustomerName", ListSortDirection.Ascending);
}
```

It's failing on the Clear() method.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access controls from the constructor in WPF, they're not initialized w/ their data etc.  I think the Loaded event is what you want to use, but check the other lifecycle events here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754221.aspx for more info.

Comment: Thanks. I tried moving the sort method call to the loaded event, but I still get an exception.

Comment: set a breakpoint on the first line of SorCustomerList and see what's null.